# GMapv3 + displaying all markers + polylines at once?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to draw all of your markers & polylines on a gmap v3 at once instead of as they occur? When you create a marker like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: mTitle,
    content: genInfo,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    position: pathCoordinates[i],
    icon: iconImg,
    stObj: stObj,
    emtObj: emtObj
});
```

It appears to draw it on the `map` you give it at `map: map`. I'd like to hold off on drawing any markers until I have them all created and ready to go at the same time. The reason is I'm doing map refreshes and for every polyline and related group of markers I draw they are showing up sequentially all over the map. I want them to all appear simultaneously instead. Here's the polyline snipet:

```
var path = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: pathCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: randcolor,
        strokeOpacity: 10,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });
    path.setMap(gmap);
```

Comment: Have you wrote some special code to display them sequetially ?

Comment: similar to your polyline, you don't have to specify the map attribute in the mapOptions when creating a marker.  Instead you can call `marker.setMap(map);` later on.  You'd probably have to add the markers to an array and loop over it, adding them all one at atime

Comment: @duncan, yes that helped me solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I'll add my comment as an answer (or if there was more to it than that you can answer your own question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to your polyline, you don't have to specify the map attribute in the mapOptions when creating a marker.

Instead you can call `marker.setMap(map);` later on.

You'd probably have to add the markers to an array and loop over it, adding them all one at a time.